# Where can I find what MEPs were attending a plenary session?

Tags: european-union, parliament

Mr. Juncker complained that [only 30 or so out of 751 MEPs turned up](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-europe-40492396) for a debate.

Where can I find a list of who those are?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the European Parliament only releases official attendance records of MEPs which can be found [on Europarl's website](http://www.europarl.europa.eu/plenary/en/minutes.html). Today's (4 July) attendance records are not available yet.

However, the official attendance list only records the MEPs who signed the attendance registry. They can theoretically [sign, vote and leave afterwards](http://www.politico.eu/article/jean-claude-juncker-european-parliament-is-ridiculous/). In this way, their attendance is taken, even though they may not attend the whole debate session.

> Despite all this, the Parliament has grappled with MEP absenteeism in plenaries for years.
>
> “People come here to sign the attendance registry, vote and then they leave,” said one Parliament official, speaking on condition of anonymity.

This article [described it too](http://www.express.co.uk/news/uk/824593/Brexit-news-Jean-Claude-Juncker-slams-absent-MEPs-European-Parliament-Strasbourg):

> Mr Juncker’s comments will compound the ill feeling towards the European Union, as MEPs are handed a tax-free allowance if they sign in for votes which are held at lunchtime.
>
> This often means MEPs do not turn up to morning debates and don’t have to in order to claim their daily amount of £268 (€306), which comes from the bloc’s coffers made up of contributions from its member states.

So, the only way likely will be to search through news articles for those in attendance. Among those in attendance were Philippe Lamberts (president of the Greens group), Tanja Fajon (a Socialist from Slovenia) and David Casa (a Maltese member of EPP).

Comment: Useful answer, but not sure if I would trust the Daily Express on this, as it is quite known for spreading [Euromyths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euromyth).